# How many methods do we have to keep String type in Solidity?

Tags: solidity, string

**How many methods do we have to keep String type in Solidity?**
Explain the Visibility Quantifiers in Solidity language in detail

Comment: The question isn't very clear, what do you mean by *to keep String type in Solidity*? For the functions specifiers you can start reading this https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.13/cheatsheet.html#function-visibility-specifiers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Explain the Visibility Quantifiers in Solidity language in detail**

Visibility Quantifiers
Following are various visibility quantifiers for functions/state variables of a contract.

external − External functions are meant to be called by other contracts. They cannot be used for internal call. To call external function within contract this.function_name() call is required. State variables cannot be marked as external.

public − Public functions/ Variables can be used both externally and internally. For public state variable, Solidity automatically creates a getter function.

internal − Internal functions/ Variables can only be used internally or by derived contracts.

private − Private functions/ Variables can only be used internally and not even by derived contracts.